# ZF2 Apigility Rest - unable to get multiple params

Tags: php, api, rest, zend-framework2

I'm using Apigility to build my Rest APIs.

I want to build have the ability to take in multiple parameters. Such as

`http://mydomain.com/users/1/activities/4`

I now this is possible from this page: https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility/issues/10

I have edit my module route to:

`'route' => '/users/:users_id/activities[/:activities_id]',`

But, I don't know how to retrieve users_id from the url.

I tried grabbing the params in my Resource php

```
    $evt = $this->getEvent();
    $params = $evt->getParams();
    die(var_dump($params));
```

But, that only returns

```
object(ArrayObject)#748 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
}
```

I'm a little baffled. Please advice.

Thanks!

Comment: inside my controller i get them params like this. $this->Params('users_id'). Same way you can get it for activities. Or $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('users_id').

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Zend Framework 2, you can use the [RouteMatch](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html) to get the parameters of a route. For your case, you could try this :

```
    $e = $this->getEvent();
    $route = $e->getRouteMatch();
    $usr_id = $match->getParam('users_id');
```

The `user_id` is now in the `$usr_id` variable.

Comment: Nice! Thanks! I really full grasp the difference between all these events, route, etc. But, I will get a hang of it.

Comment: Or short: $this->getEvent()->getRouteParam('users_id');

Answer (score 1):

Inside my controller i get them params like this.

```
$this->Params('users_id');
```

Same way you can get it for activities. Or

```
$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('users_id');
```

if your url was example.com/users?users_id=123&activites_id=123 then you could get both by calling

```
$this->params()->fromQuery()
```

and the result would be

```
Array (
    [users_id] => 123
    [activities_id] => 123
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best method is like this, you do a number of things in a single line of code and as far as I am concerned this is best practice:

```
    $user_id    = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('users_id', 0);
    $activities_id    = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('activities_id', 0);
```

1. You know the ID should be an integer so you cast this.
2. If the users_id is not mandatory, it will be set to 0 which you can then run a check against...

   ```
   if (0 === $user_id) {
       //Do some stuff
   }
   ```

This is how I do pretty much all my routes.